# What is the reference to the given hadith?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

> And from his narration on the authority of Ibn ‘Abbas that he said regarding the interpretation of Allah’s saying (Surah Nun):
>
> > ‘(Nun) He says: Allah swears by the Nun, which is the whale that carries the earths on its back while in Water, and beneath which is the Bull and under the Bull is the Rock and under the Rock is the Dust and none knows what is under the Dust save Allah.

Comment: You most likely got this from Tanwir Al-Miqbas. You should know that that book is not considered authentic according to the scholars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a hadith but a saying attributed to Ibn Abbas. It is recorded by various tafsirs such as [Tafsir al-Tabari](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura68-aya1.html#tabary). It exists in 
[Israelite](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/87835/14736) reports which is likely its source, see [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/114861/false-reports-about-the-earth-being-placed-on-the-back-of-a-bull)